# Migrating project from NBAndroid (NetBeans) to Eclipse for Android dev

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, project

I have a NBAndroid project that I've spent a fair amount of time working on and need to move over to Eclipse. My choice of NetBeans was simply one of preference but I did not realize at the time that Eclipse is really the best way to go for Android dev (since Google's tools are all focused around Eclipse). I was wondering if anyone has had experience moving a NetBeans Android project from NetBeans to Eclipse. There's tons of info about going the other way, but not much about this way. Please let me know your advice and/or experiences. Thanks.